# How do I copy weights and biases from a larger layer to a smaller layer (or vice versa)?

Tags: keras, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on a genetic algorithm. I want the model sizes to be able to change through mutation, with layers being added or removed and the number of neurons changing. But this causes me to run into the problem of how to perform crossover with models that aren't the same size.

I do have a crappy solution already worked out. But I wanted to ask if there was some public method already developed for doing this sort of thing.

I'm doing this in Keras, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

child is the keras model that will be returned. The two parent models are the models being bred.

```
def slow_crossover(self, parent1, parent2, child_num):
        '''A crossover/mutation function designed to work with models that can change sizes.'''
        if self.additional_info: print(f"================================\nChild {child_num}:")
        # 
        # Crossover
        #

        # Get all genes from parent2
        # This will prevent the model from trying to take a gene section from parent2 but it being the wrong size
        p2_genes = [] # [weights, biases]
        for layer in parent2.layers:
            # Get weight/bias data and empty lists to store genes
            p2_data = layer.get_weights()
            weight, bias = [], []
            # Get the weight genes
            for x in range(p2_data[0].shape[0]):
                for y in range(self.gene_size, p2_data[0].shape[1], self.gene_size):
                        weight.append(p2_data[0][x][(y-self.gene_size):y])
            # Get the bias genes
            for x in range(self.gene_size, p2_data[1].shape[0], self.gene_size):
                bias.append(p2_data[1][(x-self.gene_size):x])
            p2_genes.append([weight, bias])

        # Crossover genes
        child_crossover = []
        for i in range(len(parent1.layers)):
            # Get weights and biases of the parents
            # p1_data acts as the base for the child
            p1_data = parent1.layers[i].get_weights()

            # The layer we use for p2, since they might have different numbers of layers
            p2_layer = int(i * len(parent2.layers) / len(parent1.layers))

            # Handle the weights
            for x in range(p1_data[0].shape[0]):
                for y in range(self.gene_size, p1_data[0].shape[1], self.gene_size):
                    # Check to see if crossover should occur
                    # Make sure there's genes available to be used
                    try:
                        if len(p2_genes[p2_layer][0]) and (random() < self.crossover_rate):
                            p1_data[0][x][(y-self.gene_size):y] = p2_genes[p2_layer][0][int((y / p1_data[0].shape[1]) * len(p2_genes[p2_layer][0]))]
                    except:
                        print(f"\nFailed to crossover weight. (list index out of range? -> {p2_layer}, {len(p2_genes)}, {i}, {len(parent1.layers)}, {len(parent2.layers)}\n")

                    # Handle the biases
                    # Check to see if crossover should occur
                    try:
                        if len(p2_genes[p2_layer][1]) and (random() < self.crossover_rate):
                            p1_data[1][(y-self.gene_size):y] = p2_genes[p2_layer][1][int((y / p1_data[1].shape[0]) * len(p2_genes[p2_layer][1]))]
                    except:
                        print(f"\nFailed to crossover bias. (list index out of range? -> {p2_layer}, {len(p2_genes)}, {i}, {len(parent1.layers)}, {len(parent2.layers)}\n")
            
            # Collect the layer data after crossover
            child_crossover.append(p1_data)

        # 
        # Mutate
        #

        # Value lists
        modded_layer = [False for i in range(len(child_crossover))]
        hidden_layers = []

        #
        # Mutate number of neurons
        for i in range(len(child_crossover) - 1):
            num_neurons = child_crossover[i][0].shape[1]
            # Check to see if the size of this layer will mutate
            if (random() < self.mutation_rate):
                num_neurons += 1 if (random() > 0.5) else -1
                if self.additional_info: print("Neuron count changed!")
            hidden_layers.append(num_neurons)

        #
        # Mutate number of hidden layers
        if (random() < self.mutation_rate):
            # Remove layer
            if len(hidden_layers) and (random() > 0.5):
                # Choose layer to remove
                location = randint(0, len(hidden_layers)-1)
                del hidden_layers[location]
                # We've removed it, so we don't want to try to copy it
                modded_layer.insert(location, True)
                if self.additional_info: print("Removed hidden layer!")
            # Add layer
            else:
                # Choose where to insert the new layer and how many neurons it should have
                location = randint(0, len(hidden_layers))
                num_neurons = randint(1, 10)
                # Insert layer
                hidden_layers.insert(location, num_neurons)
                modded_layer.insert(location, True)
                if self.additional_info: print("Added hidden layer!")

        #
        # Copy weights and biases, then mutate individual weights and biases
        child = LinearNet.linear_QNet(child_crossover[0][0].shape[0], child_crossover[-1][0].shape[1], hidden_layers=hidden_layers, random_model=False)
        p_counter = 0
        for i in range(len(child.layers)):
            # Copy old weight and bias values over to new model and mutate them, if it's not a new layer
            child_data = child.layers[i].get_weights()
            if not modded_layer[i]:
                _x = child_data[0].shape[0] if child_data[0].shape[0] < child_crossover[p_counter][0].shape[0] else child_crossover[p_counter][0].shape[0]
                _y = child_data[0].shape[1] if child_data[0].shape[1] < child_crossover[p_counter][0].shape[1] else child_crossover[p_counter][0].shape[1]
                child_data[0][0:_x, 0:_y] = child_crossover[p_counter][0][0:_x, 0:_y]
                child_data[1][0:_y] = child_crossover[p_counter][1][0:_y]

                for x in range(_x):
                    # Check for weight mutation
                    for y in range(_y):
                        if (random() < self.mutation_rate):
                            child_data[0][x][y] += uniform(-self.mutation_degree, self.mutation_degree)
                        
                        # Check for bias mutation
                        if ((len(child.layers) - i) - 1) and (random() < self.mutation_rate):
                            child_data[1][y] += uniform(-self.mutation_degree, self.mutation_degree)
                
                p_counter += 1
            # Set weights and biases in child
            child.layers[i].build(input_shape=child_data[0].shape[0])
            child.layers[i].set_weights(child_data)
        
        print(f"Agent {i}")
        [print(f"Layer {j}: {layer.get_weights()[0].shape}") for j, layer in enumerate(child.layers)]
        print("")

        return child
```